# Obj-c - reload tableView with updated NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to reload my tableView with new data (self.filtered, an NSMutableArray). In order to do this, my understanding is that i need to remove all objects from the original self.filtered and then repopulate it with the updated NSMutableArray. For some reason when I run the below however, I get the following crash error (and yes, all values are populated as they should be...e.g. no null responses):

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI removeAllObjects]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x28009c540'

**Viewcontroller.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *filtered;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *myID = [session user][@"user"][@"uid"];

    NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid ==[cd] %@", targetedUser];
    NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"targetuser ==[cd] %@", myID];
    NSPredicate *p3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid ==[cd] %@", myID];
    NSPredicate *p4 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"targetuser ==[cd] %@", targetedUser];
    NSPredicate *p5 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"targetuser ==[cd] %@", universal];

    NSCompoundPredicate *pIntermediary1 = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p1, p2]];
    NSCompoundPredicate * pIntermediary2 = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p3, p4]];
    NSCompoundPredicate * pIntermediary3 = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p1, p5]];
    NSCompoundPredicate *pFinal = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[pIntermediary1, pIntermediary2, pIntermediary3]];

    self.filtered = [self.messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pFinal];
}

- (IBAction)sendReply:(id)sender {
    NSMutableArray *aArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:self.filtered,nil];
    NSLog(@"BEFORE IT %@", aArr);

    [aArr addObject:nodeData];

    [self.filtered removeAllObjects];
    [self.filtered addObject:aArr];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"LASTLY %@", self.filtered);
}
```

There are no NSArrays in this method - only NSMutableArrays, so I'm not sure why this is happening?

Comment: Your `filtered` property contains an immutable array, not a mutable array, hence the error. Show how you declared that property and show how you assigned a value to it.

Comment: BTW - the line `[self.filtered addObject:aArr];` adds the whole array to the array. It does not add the objects of `aArr` directly to `filtered`. In other words, you are left with an array of array. Is that what you want?

Comment: Look closely at your error message and see that you are trying to call `removeAllObjects` against an `NSArray`, not an `NSMutableArray` as you expect.

Comment: @rmaddy See updated

Comment: Ahh @CodeBender see above edits. So at the end of viewDidLoad my self.filtered becomes immutable? How can I make it so that it's mutable again?

Comment: @rmaddy I want to add the objects of aArr directly to filtered :) Makes more sense lol what should that line look like instead? Just realized I was adding the entire array...

Comment: Use `addObjectsFromArray:` instead of `addObject:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
self.filtered = [self.messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pFinal];
```

gives you an `NSArray`, not an `NSMutableArray`.

Change that to:

```
self.filtered = [[self.messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pFinal] mutableCopy];
```

and then your code will work a lot better. Check for this on any line that attempts to set the `filtered` property.

Separate from that issue is the line:

```
[self.filtered addObject:aArr];
```

This is adding the array to the array, it is not directly adding the objects of `aArr` to `filtered`.

Either change this line to:

```
[self.filtered addObjectsFromArray:aArr];
```

or replace the lines:

```
[self.filtered removeAllObjects];
[self.filtered addObject:aArr];
```

with:

```
self.filtered = aArr;
```

Comment: Updated! That said, when I reload my tableview at the very end, the data still doesnt update :/ Why is this?